# El Bot no me detecta una imagen pero las otras si Python

Tags: python-3.x

estoy haciendo un bot todo me va muy bien pero tengo un error que ya no se como solucionarlo.
un sprite no me lo detecta por mas que lo intento. Este es my codigo:
primero
1 el bot efectuara movimiento en el juego
2 luego analizara la pantalla de juego, si detecta un sprite efectuara una acción como por ejemplo la funcion battle,
3 si no detecta ningun sprite repetira el bucle
Me detecta casi todos los sprites menos el primero que es la variable ditto, ya no se que hacer me pueden ayudar?

```
import keyboard
import pyautogui as ptg
import time
from ahk import AHK

def bot():
    while True:
        if keyboard.is_pressed("g"):
            tiempo = 10
            while tiempo > 0:
                if 0 < tiempo:
                    print("el bot se detendra en %g" % tiempo)
                    time.sleep(1)
                    tiempo -= 1
                else:
                    pass
                ptg.alert(text='se ha detenido el bot', title='alert', button='OK')
                break
        else:
            run()
            time.sleep(10)
            ditto = ptg.locateOnScreen("source/pokemons/ditto.png", confidence=0.9)
            if ditto != None:
                print("ditto encontrado")
                moves()
                if moves() != None:
                    pass
                else:
                    print("No se encuentra movimiento falsotortazo")
                    tiempo = 10
                    while tiempo > 0:
                        if 0 < tiempo:
                            print("el bot se detendra en %g" % tiempo)
                            time.sleep(1)
                            tiempo -= 1
                        else:
                            pass
                        ptg.alert(text='se ha detenido el bot', title='alert', button='OK')
                        break
                time.sleep(20)
                captura()
                if captura == None:
                    print("No hay pokeballs")
                    tiempo = 10
                    while tiempo > 0:
                        if 0 < tiempo:
                            print("el bot se detendra en %g" % tiempo)
                            time.sleep(1)
                            tiempo -= 1
                        else:
                            pass
                        ptg.alert(text='se ha detenido el bot', title='alert', button='OK')
                        break
                continue
            else:
                pass
            sditto = ptg.locateOnScreen("source/pokemons/dittoS.png", confidence=0.9)
            if sditto == None:
                pass
            else:
                print("dittoS encontrado")
                moves()
                if moves() != None:
                    pass
                else:
                    print("No se encuentra movimiento falsotortazo")
                    tiempo = 10
                    while tiempo > 0:
                        if 0 < tiempo:
                            print("el bot se detendra en %g" % tiempo)
                            time.sleep(1)
                            tiempo -= 1
                        else:
                            pass
                        ptg.alert(text='se ha detenido el bot', title='alert', button='OK')
                        break
                time.sleep(20)
                captura()
            if captura == None:
                print("No hay pokeballs")
                tiempo = 10
                while tiempo > 0:
                    if 0 < tiempo:
                        print("el bot se detendra en %g" % tiempo)
                        time.sleep(1)
                        tiempo -= 1
                    else:
                        pass
                    ptg.alert(text='se ha detenido el bot', title='alert', button='OK')
                    break
                continue
            else:
                pass
            loudred_s = ptg.locateOnScreen("source/pokemons/loudredS.png", confidence=0.9)
        if loudred_s == None:
            pass
        else:
            print("loudredS encontrado")
            moves()
            if moves() != None:
                pass
            else:
                print("No se encuentra movimiento falsotortazo")
                tiempo = 10
                while tiempo > 0:
                    if 0 < tiempo:
                        print("el bot se detendra en %g" % tiempo)
                        time.sleep(1)
                        tiempo -= 1
                    else:
                        pass
                    ptg.alert(text='se ha detenido el bot', title='alert', button='OK')
                    break
            time.sleep(20)
            captura()
        if captura == None:
            print("No hay pokeballs")
            tiempo = 10
            while tiempo > 0:
                if 0 < tiempo:
                    print("el bot se detendra en %g" % tiempo)
                    time.sleep(1)
                    tiempo -= 1
                else:
                    pass
                ptg.alert(text='se ha detenido el bot', title='alert', button="aceptar")
                break
            continue
        else:
            pass
        scape()
        if scape == None:
            pass
        else:
            continue
        continue
            


def main():
    tiempo = 20
    while tiempo > 0:
        if 0 < tiempo:
            print("seleccione la ventana de PokeMMO antes de %g" % tiempo)
            time.sleep(1)
            tiempo -= 1
        else:
            print("Bot iniciado...")
            pass
    bot()


main()
```

las imagenes de los sprites son [image: ditto] [image: dittoS] y [image: loudredS]

Comment: Lograste solucionarlo?, y, pudiste terminar el proyecto?

Comment: por supuesto, en ves de usar sprites completos solo usé los sprites de los nombres de cada pokemon